# Timeout::Error with Selenium/Capybara/Cucumber/Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

We are facing issue when we are executing the scenarios in cucumber ruby using Capybara. After few Scenarios are executed, we are getting time out error and not able to proceed to next scenario.

Following error is displayed

```
Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error)
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rbuf_fill'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2563:in `read_status_line'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2552:in `read_new'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1320:in `block in transport_request'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1317:in `catch'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1317:in `transport_request'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1294:in `request'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1287:in `block in request'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:746:in `start'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1285:in `request'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.37.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:83:in `response_for'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.37.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:39:in `request'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.37.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.37.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:634:in `raw_execute'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.37.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:612:in `execute'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.37.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:361:in `deleteAllCookies'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.37.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/options.rb:67:in `delete_all_cookies'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:84:in `reset!'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:77:in `reset!'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara.rb:245:in `block in reset_sessions!'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara.rb:245:in `each'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara.rb:245:in `reset_sessions!'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/cucumber.rb:10:in `After'
```

We are using Capybara 2.1.0 version and Cucumber 1.3.8.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: capybara 2.1.0 is over 2 years old, as is selenium-webdriver-2.37 - if you can udpate those I would try that first.

Comment: Also see this if you're testing with  chrome - https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1035 - and check what version of chromedriver you're using

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response . We updated the capybara version to 2.5.0 and selenium web driver to 2.48.  Seems like the issue is not resolved with updated version also. kindly suggest an alternate solution.

Comment: Is this Chrome, or Firefox or both? As indicated above, make sure you are using the latest chromedriver (2.20 right now)